# How to prove absolute lack of correlation

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, mathematical-statistics, neural-networks, model

I have a huge dataset of 17 variables. I intended to use 15 of those to predict the 17th, and I could not find any model (ANN) to do so. I know that one of those variables definitely predicts the dependent.

With what mathematical basis could I prove that there is absolutely no correlation, linear or otherwise, between the dependent and the 15 others?

Answer (score 1):

> absolutely no correlation, linear or otherwise,

This is impossible. In the best case you can get p-value of the correlation coefficient, and reject it at a given significance level, but you can't prove that the variables are [independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29), because it seems that's what you're aiming for.

To prove independence you need to know the joint distribution. Usually, it's impossible to recover from data. In rare cases you could try to infer the joint distribution when you know the parametric form of the joint distribution.

Comment: I thought about kernel PCA. Can you recommend a mathematical technique to present a $p$-value for non-linear correlations?

Comment: What's non-linear correlation? Do you mean Spearman rank correlation or something like that?

Comment: Yes, or any sort of nonlinear response surface.

Comment: For Spearman's rank correlation see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance).